# Javascript object required (IE8)

Tags: javascript, object, internet-explorer-8, required

javascript for elements re-size works fine on my tumblr theme, but I get the object required error on the following line in IE8:

`fschildren = $("fs_wrapper").childNodes;`

Thanks for help
Peter

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function resizedivs() {

$ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

fschildren = $("fs_wrapper").childNodes;
postc = 0;
thedivs = new Array();

for(i = 0; i < fschildren.length; i++) {
    if(fschildren[i].tagName == "DIV") {
        thedivs[postc] = fschildren[i];
        postc++;
    }
}

newwidth = 0;
for(i = 0; i < thedivs.length; i++) {
    if(newwidth <= document.body.clientWidth) {
        newwidth = newwidth + (thedivs[i].clientWidth)+15;
    }

    if(newwidth >= document.body.clientWidth || newwidth >= 1300) { // 100 for padding minus 15 extra
        newwidth = newwidth - (thedivs[i].clientWidth+15);
        break;
    }
}

$("fs_wrapper").style.width = newwidth-0+"px";
$("fs_wrapper").style.position = "relative";
$("fs_wrapper").style.left = "0px";

$("sec2").style.width = newwidth-0+"px";
$("sec2").style.position = "relative";
$("sec2").style.left = "0px";

$("sec3").style.width = newwidth-0+"px";
$("sec3").style.position = "relative";
$("sec3").style.left = "0px";

}

window.onresize = function() {
    resizedivs();

}

window.onload = function() {
    resizedivs();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think you are missing `#` or `.` before `fs_wrapper`

Comment: Assuming jquery & an ID;  `$("#fs_wrapper")[0].childNodes`

Comment: Any change with . or # caused corrupted code. So I added the whole script to show you all consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Does object really exist?

```
myObj = document.getElementById('myObj');
if(!myObj) {
  alert("4004 not found");
  return;
}
```

You are missing the right selector `.` for class or `#` for id

see this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp